# Why is my hubconnection on but the method is not being fired?

Tags: signalr, blazor

I've set up signalr in my blazor server side application and for some reason this hubconnection is not being triggered, when the hubconnection is on, it completely ignores the BroadcastData method and doesnt even fire it:

```
private HubConnection hubConnection;
private string _hubUrl;

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
string baseUrl = NavigationManager.BaseUri;
            _hubUrl = baseUrl.TrimEnd('/') + SignalRHub.HubUrl;
            _hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
                .WithUrl(_hubUrl)
                .Build();
hubConnection.On<ClientDTO>("BroadcastData", BroadcastData);
await hubConnection.StartAsync();
}

private void BroadcastData(ClientDTO payload)
    {
        dashboardData = payload;
        StateHasChanged();
    }
```

I have everything setup for this to be "working" but clearly it isn't working and I'm completely lost at what could be the problem... Please take a look at what I have so far and see if you can see what's going on:

Startup:

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
   Configuration = configuration;
   StartTimer();
}

private void StartTimer()
        {
            _timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
            _timer.Interval = 5000;
            _timer.Elapsed += TimerElapsed;
            _timer.Start();
        }

private void TimerElapsed(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            Trigger();
        }

public void Trigger()
        {
            try
            {
                using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    //Trigger on elapsed
                    var response = client.GetAsync(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ApiTriggerURL")).Result;
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("something terrible has happened...");
            }
        }

services.AddScoped(typeof(SignalRHub));
services.AddScoped<IHub, SignalRHub>();
services.AddScoped<HttpClient>();
            services.AddSignalR();

            services.AddResponseCompression(opts =>
            {
                opts.MimeTypes = ResponseCompressionDefaults.MimeTypes.Concat(
                    new[] { "application/octet-stream" });
            });

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilde app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
   app.UseResponseCompression();
   app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
                endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host"); 
                endpoints.MapHub<SignalRHub>(SignalRHub.HubUrl);
            });
}
```

appsettings.json: (fyi, the trigger is working, the api endpoint is being hit as it returns a status 200 ok result)

```
"ConnectionStrings": 
{
     "ApiTriggerURL": "http://localhost:5000/api/SignalRHub/GetMyData"
}
```

Then we have my api controller: (here you can see the status 200 ok)

```
private readonly SignalRHub _signalRHub;

        public SignalRHubController(SignalRHub signalRHub)
        {
            _signalRHub = signalRHub;
        }

[HttpGet]
        public ObjectResult GetMyData()
        {
            try
            {
                Task.WhenAll(_signalRHub.BroadcastData());  // Call hub broadcast method
                return this.StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.OK, "trigger has been triggered");
            }
            catch
            {
                return this.StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "christ, the ting is broken fam");
            }
        }
```

When we look into the _signalRHub.BroadcastData(), we see this:

```
public class SignalRHub : Hub, IHub
{
    private readonly ClientService _clientService;
    readonly IHubContext<SignalRHub> _hubContext;

    public const string HubUrl = "/chathub"; //this is being read in the startup in the endpoints

    public SignalRHub(ClientService clientService, IHubContext<SignalRHub> hubContext)
        {
            _clientService = clientService;
            _hubContext = hubContext;
           
        }

public async Task BroadcastData()
        {
            var data = _clientService .GetDataAsync().Result;
            await _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("BroadcastData", data); //send data to all clients  
        }
}
```

And this in turn should basically do this signalrhub every x seconds (depending on timer)
I know my code is a whole load of madness, but please look pass this and help me to understand why this isn't working! Thank you in advance!

Comment: For reference of where I got some of the code from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-tutorial-build-blazor-server-chat-app

Comment: Please show the code where you connect to the hub. something like `new HubConnectionBuilder().WithUrl(_hubUrl).Build();`

Comment: This page may be a later reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr-blazor?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio&pivots=server

Comment: @BrianParker Hi brian! I have updated the post with the requested code, if you need anymore of the code, please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
hubConnection.On<ClientDTO>("BroadcastData", (payload)=>
BroadcastData(payload);
);
```

Instead of

```
hubConnection.On<ClientDTO>("BroadcastData", BroadcastData);
```